# Placing RGBA on top of Direct X in the same application

Tags: directx, direct3d, rgba

I have in my application 2 child windows.
The first one is rendering Direct3D stuff
The second one takes an BGRA picture and needs to place it on top (with transparent areas)
From playing around with it, even if I put the BGRA window's z order as the top level, my 
Direct3D window is still obscuring my BGRA  one.

Is there any way in which I can place the BGRA window (which is larger) on top of the Direct3D one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [layered windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#layered)? As far as I know, that is how most simple game addons do their overlays, so I'm guessing it actually works with Direct3D.

If you require more specific instructions on how to setup a layered window, you'll need to tell us a bit more about your programming environment (C++, C#, etc).

Comment: Actually, hijacking the D3D render context and working within that is far more common (that's how Fraps, Steam, MGE, OBGE, NWShader, ENB all work). I've never seen layered windows used for this, which is odd as it looks like a convenient solution.

Comment: Afaik, hijacking the render context is only necessary if you want to _process_ (read and/or modify) the contents, which is what all those addons you mentioned do. For a simple overlay (no processing, no fullscreen stuff... just things like maps and stats), that isn't necessary.

Comment: I'm looking for something that changes: I want the BGRA thingy to change through time (I am rendering it every few hundreds of milliseconds) and then place it on a live video feed running at 30 fps.